# Save Android project to run on PC (eclipse)

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

Is it possible to convert or to just export an Android project from eclipse to run on a PC without an emulator (like .exe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, that's not possible, since Android uses the `Dalvik VM` wich is inbuilt in every emulator. Deploying and `.apk` file in the emulator is the fastest and easiest way when having no device.

The Dalvik vm is a complete environment wich is not included (or sth) on windows:

[image]

Comment: Aah ok, that's a bummer! I've been learning to program for Android, and now I was asked to develop a rather simple application that has to be able to run on a PC. As I understand, programming for Android is quite different from programming for PC?

Comment: Programming it isn't (so) different as normal Java, but the underlying VM and architecture is! ByTheWay: upvotes if you like my answer would be great ;)

Comment: There actually have been a number of schemes for wrapping an android app with the necessary support components to enable it to run on a PC, without emulating a foreign processor.  None of them seem to have massively taken off, but that may be as much a result of the constrained device UI not being a wonderful user experience on a machine with a larger screen, mouse, and keyboard.

Comment: Ok! When programming for PC, is it still like working with .xml-files together with the java-files?
I would if I could, but I'm afraid I don't have enough reputation points yet =P

Comment: afaik you could accept my answer, that'll be great ^^(if not: questioning but not accepting? what a crap ^^)

Comment: I have now accepted your answer, thank you! Do you have any advice on how to easily learn to make an application that is executable on a PC? I would like for the user to add text in different fonts and colors onto another picture and then save the picture on the hard drive.

Comment: Maybe you could put most of the code in a java lib (jar file) and include it in the androidVersion as well as in an javaSE version...